# Bio metric Device - ZD2F20

Tags: c#, biometrics

I need to place some entity (User/Enroll) based data on this particular bio metric device (ZD2F20). It provides some properties for User and Device.

```
 public enum UserProperty
        {
            UserName = 0,
            Enroll = 1,
            UserExtInfo = 2,
            AccessControlSettings = 3,
            Messages = 4,
            Privilege = 5,
        }

Connection.SetProperty(UserProperty property, Object extraProperty, User CurrentUser, Object extraData);
e.g. 
Connection.SetProperty(UserProperty.Enroll, extraProperty, CurrentUser, null);
```

For other properties its working fine, but for enroll property its giving me the following error
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Maybe it requires `extraData` not to be `null`?

Comment: I have tried by passing other values for extraData by making it bool/string. In other cases it takes it as a string, and it contains the version number as a value. I have done this one too. Still its giving same error :(

Comment: Can you show us the Connection.SetProperty method ?

Comment: So you just passed random data? Is there no documentation? What if this was a nuclear bomb?

Comment: @deathismyfriend well I can't attached images/screenshots. I have just joined stackoverflow.

Comment: @leppie hahaha. There were only 2 guides in the box. User Guide & Installation Guide. :(

Comment: private void setUserInfoButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (OpenDevice())
    {
        CurrentUser = null;
        InitUser();
        extraProperty = true;
        if(!Connection.SetProperty(UserProperty.UserName, extraProperty, CurrentUser, null))
            OperateError();
        CloseDevice();
    }
    else
         OperateError();
}

OpenDevice is working fine as it makes connection with the device. InItUser makes an object of User type and fills it fields by fetching data from UI.

Comment: Did you try their website maybe? Perhaps they have an SDK? Perhaps you are not to mess with it ;p

Comment: Link for downloading SDK C#

http://www.realandbio.hk/download/sdk/ZD2F20-SDK.rar


Extract it and open project Riss.Device.ConnectionTester under folder named Sample for C# SDK


You can find the implementation for insertion of user entity on device in
Home.xaml.cs file, and on line number 788